# Validação relacionamento multi-empresa mysql

Tags: mysql, typescript, orm

**Problema:** uma empresa pode associar registros que não são dela, apenas informando o id no relacionamento

**Cenário:** Minha API é multi-empresa e cada empresa gerencia seus registros (produtos, pedidos ...), mas essas empresas só podem visualizar e usar registros que lhes pertençam. No entanto, é possível inserir um id de um produto de outra empresa em um pedido e não deveria

**Examplo:** A empresa Apple só pode informar o produto do iPhone em seus pedidos, caso tente informar o Google Pixel deveria aparecer alguma mensagem de erro

**Observações:** Espero não precisar validar cada registro associado ao pedido antes de salvá-lo, pois meu esquema real possui vários relacionamentos (20 tabelas associadas a um pedido, cerca de 2 níveis em cascata) e este é apenas um pequeno exemplo. Seria muito complicado pesquisar o banco de dados para cada produto e verificar se ele pertence à empresa. Eu acho que seria possível evitar essa gravação com alguma configuração de índice

**Questão:** Como posso evitar a associação de registros de outras empresas com os registros atuais da empresa, mesmo informando o id no corpo da requisição?

Agradeço sua ajuda, pois tenho um sistema em produção com essa situação.

**company.entity.ts**

```
@Entity()
export class Company {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @OneToMany(() => Product, (product) => product.company)
  products: Product[];

  @OneToMany(() => Order, (order) => order.company)
  orders: Order[];
}
```

**product.entity.ts**

```
@Entity()
export class Product {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  description: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Company, (company) => company.products)
  company: Company;
}
```

**order.entity.ts**

```
@Entity()
export class Order {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  description: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Company, (company) => company.orders)
  company: Company;

  @ManyToMany(() => Product)
  @JoinTable()
  products: Product[];
}
```

**order.controller.ts**

```
@Controller('orders')
export class OrderController {

  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Order)
    public repository: Repository<Order>,
  ) { }

  @Post()
  public async create(@Body() body: Order): Promise<Order> {
    body.id = undefined;
    body = await this.repository.save(body);
    return await this.repository.findOne(body.id, { relations: ['products'] });
  }

  @Put(':id')
  public async update(@Param('id') id, @Body() body: Order): Promise<Order> {
    body.id = Number(id);
    await this.repository.save(body);
    return await this.repository.findOne(id, { relations: ['products'] });
  }
}
```

**Tabela de Empresa**

- **id**: 1 **description**: Apple
- **id**: 2 **description**: Google

**Tabela de Produto**

- **id**: 1 **description**: iPhone **companyId:** 1
- **id**: 2 **description**: Google Pixel **companyId**: 2

**POST http://localhost:3040/orders**
Body Request:
Obs.: aqui o usuário informa o iPhone que é um produto que ele conhece, e força o produto com id 2, sendo que esse é um produto desconhecido, pois api só retorna os que produtos são visíveis para a Apple, neste caso apenas o iPhone

```js
{
    "company": 1,
    "description": "Order 001",
    "products": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "description": "iPhone"
        },
        {
            "id": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

Body Response:
Obs.: Mesmo informando o produto de outra empresa, no retorno da api é apresentado o Google Pixel que não pôde ser registrado no pedido da Apple. Aqui você deve ter uma mensagem de erro

```js
{
    "id": 2,
    "description": "Order 001",
    "products": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "description": "iPhone"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "description": "Google Pixel"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Resultados**

Tabela de Pedido

[image]

Tabela de Produtos do Pedido

[image]

**Notas:**

1. A solução de validar se o pedido pode ser salvo com base na constante do ID da empresa que o usuário está logado, apenas funciona para o primeiro nível, no caso o pedido. A questão é que os produtos relacionados no pedido, podem não vir com o campo de empresa informado, apenas com o ID
2. Realmente não vejo como uma solução elegante e reaproveitável consultar produto por produto no banco de dados verificando se ele pertence a empresa ou não, acredito que o próprio mysql poderia ter alguma forma de validar pela chave estrangeira se o registro pode ser associado ao não no momento da gravação pelo ORM

Comment: Traduza a pergunta  e poste novamente!

Comment: Making use of a WHERE condition in output to filter the item by business id would not solve?

Comment: @EliseuB. I think there may be a forced attack on the system where the hacker can report deleterious IDs and get information from other companies products. In this way, even if he gets the filtered products, he could get the wrong products by entering the ID of a product while recording an order

Comment: You can validate the output only if the product contains the company ID by validating through a CONSTANT provided by the system, and not allowing to pass the store ID in a query, but only validating the output with the CONSTANT ID provided by the system.

Comment: @EliseuB. acabei não comentando, mas o produto informado no pedido não vem com o campo de empresa informado no POST da API, no caso nem o pedido também. No exemplo, coloquei dessa forma para encurtar, mas essa informação deve vir do sessão do usuário logado. Nessa situação, busco que o usuário apenas informe o ID de cada produto no pedido e o ORM faça o relacionamento, validando se o produto é da mesma empresa apenas validando por meio de chave estrangeira